# Detailed and accepted answer deleted by a moderator - why?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I am referring [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903984/how-can-you-write-a-security-rule-to-ensure-that-a-user-can-write-to-a-cloud-fir) for which I produced a detailed self-contained answer (no link), which was accepted by the person who raised the question. So far so good.

But now I notice that my answer was deleted by a moderator, why? What policy did my answer not comply with?

And I cannot even vote to undelete it.

Attached a screenshot of my answer for those not having access[image]

I reposted my answer since.

Comment: I suspect your EDIT probably was part of the problem.  The original opening "Question" and 1 sentence probably didn't look like an answer.  I don't know what the flag interface looks like, but I have heard it mentioned it only shows the first few lines of an answer by default so the mod might not have saw your code.  Or they just misclicked (which happens)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Mods should always be careful when deleting answers and handling flags. You need to read the whole thing to understand if it is an attempt to answer or just a comment.

Comment: It would probably be helpful not to re-post until *after* this question is resolved.

Comment: You question "Why is it not safe?" doesn't help to see this as an answer. I don't see it as being answered by you, so it's still an open question. I can see that the rest of the post is indeed an answer, but why do you ask an initial question in it? (Also, you do not have to point out in the post that you've made an edit. The post should just read as if it's not a trail of revision, in my opinion)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

sorry, this answer was flagged as not an answer and was staying in the queue.

I (or another moderator) should have declined the flag, but it stayed there like a sitting duck and it seems that I misclicked on "delete", because even if it starts by a question it looks like an answer afterwards.

Sorry for this! [Wrongly deleted answer twice this week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399343/why-was-my-answer-its-a-bug-in-node-13-x-update-to-14-deleted)... Time for new mods to step in :)

Note: when this happens, *never* repost a similar answer. The correct way to go is either create a meta post or edit and then custom flag the answer (the latter is preferred in the first place to avoid possible drama). Re-posting an answer deleted by a moderator can get you suspended. Check with us/the community first.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom flag"? Is this process described somewhere?

Comment: @oliver Flag > In need of moderator intervention > write your explanation